# How to properly share a functor with state between two Loki Functors?

Tags: c++, state, functor, c++-loki

I'm using Loki::Functor for callback purposes and I wish to share a functor (object with a suitable `operator()` member function defined) between two callbacks. This functor needs to hold state so that both callbacks see it.

A quick test shows that constructing the Loki functor with a functor passed by value has a different result as to using the member function pointer constructor:

```
#include "loki/Functor.h"

struct Bar {
  int x;
  void inc() { ++x; }
  int operator()() { return x; }
  int get() { return x; }
};

Bar b;
Loki::Functor<int, Loki::NullType> f1(b);
Loki::Functor<int, Loki::NullType> f2(&b, &Bar::get);
Loki::Functor<int, Loki::NullType> f3(&b, &Bar::operator());
cout << f1() << endl;   // prints '0'
cout << f2() << endl;   // prints '0'
cout << f3() << endl;   // prints '0'
b.inc();
cout << f1() << endl;   // prints '0'
cout << f2() << endl;   // prints '1'
cout << f3() << endl;   // prints '1'
```

`f2` demonstrates that using member function pointers and a pointer to an instance results in different behaviour to `f1`. Then `f3` suggests itself as a possible way to share the functor between loki functors.

I believe `f1` relates to the 'copy semantics' supported by Loki::Functor - a copy of the functor is made, which has a new value for `x`, whereas `f2` and `f3` do what I want - the actual instance is referenced by the loki Functor and therefore shared between them.

Therefore I'd like to know if `f3` is the best way to bind the same actual instance of the functor `Bar` to two loki functors (`f2` & `f3`), or is there a better/cleaner way to do it along the lines of `f1` syntax?

EDIT: some might ask why am I using Loki given its age? It provides what I need in a constrained development environment, where global statics are strictly prohibited (I did have to remove the Small Object singleton from loki/Functor.h however, but that was easy). Happy to elaborate on the constraints if anyone has suggestions for alternative generalised functor libraries.

Comment: I'm genuinely surprised that someone is still using `Loki`. The last release was almost 8 years ago.

Comment: The latest release was in 2009. I am working in a custom environment where global static variables are not permitted (so that rules out Boost::function and bind), with a fixed version of LLVM that does not support lambdas and other useful features. Considering when Loki was written compiler support for the features it depends on was poor, but now seems to be excellent, it fits the bill pretty well for me. Of course if you know of other libraries that might be worth a look, given my constraints, I'm all ears.

Comment: Which implementation of bind/function uses global static variables? If you just mean the placeholders, that is rather easy to fix.

Comment: Yes, the placeholders in Boost - if that's easy to fix I'd be interested to know how, as I do quite like Boost::function.

Comment: Look at `boost/bind/placeholders.hpp`. You will see 3 different styles to define them. For you the one using a function seems appropriate. gcc takes a different approach and defines the placeholders as `extern const`.

Comment: Thanks, that does look promising and I will try Boost in the near future. That said, I'm still interested in any answers to the original question as I cannot switch from Loki right at this time, and it does do the job right now.

Comment: One workaround I found is to create a new functor that wraps a pointer to the shared object. When the functor is copied, the pointer is too. Then that functor simply calls `operator()` via the pointer.

Comment: I do not know Loki well enough to answer, but can't you keep the internal implementation of the functor in a shared object and manage it with a shared pointer of sorts, as you would do with a pimpl idiom. The difference being, that a pimpl class usually also copies the internal state on copy.

Comment: Yes, that's essentially what I'm doing now - I keep a reference to the stateful object with a proxy functor. The proxy gets copied but all copies reference the same actual instance of the stateful object. The "problem" seems to be limited just to passing a whole functor to Loki::Functor's constructor by value, but if I pass `(&functor_, &MyFunctor::operator())` explicitly, it references rather than copies, which is another workaround.